# Render a template in a onchage of text field in odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to render a template in onchange of a input field.

Here is the onchange method.

***.js**

```
        _onClickBasketInputChange: function(){
          console.log('inside input change',this.basketVerificationId);
          var self = this;
          var barcode = $('.basket_barcode_input').val();
          console.log('barcode',barcode);
          // var rec = this._rpc({
          return this._rpc({
            model: 'mobile.basket.verification',
            method: 'get_picking_details',
            args: [this.basketVerificationId,barcode],
          }).then(function(res){
            // console.log('this',self);
            console.log('picking_id',res);
              var $body = this.$el.filter('.o_barcode_lines');// Here i am getting the error ' Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this is undefined'
            console.log('body',$body);
            if (res['status'] == true){
              console.log('successs');
              var $lines = $(Qweb.render('basketVerificationLines', {
                picking:res['picking_id'],
                customer:res['partner_id'],
                lines:res['line_ids']
              }));
              $body.prepend($lines);

            }
            // $('.basket_barcode_input').val('');
            var message = res['result'];
            if (res['status'] == false){
              Dialog.alert(self, message);
            }
          });
        },
```

But i am getting following error
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this is undefined

Update:
When change `this` to `self`, the value of `$body` is

```
body 
  Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }
```

​
length: 0
​
prevObject: Object { 0: div.o_action, length: 1 }
​
And the template not prepend to the body.

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,
I replace the `.filter` with `.find` then it works.

```
      var $body = self.$el.find('.o_barcode_lines');
```